# Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Tengo este query:

```
private static final String GET_DIAS_FALTANTES_IN_HORARIO = 
            " SELECT temp "+ 
                    "FROM ("+       
                        "SELECT 0 AS temp " + 
            "                        UNION ALL SELECT 1 " + 
            "                        UNION ALL SELECT 2 " + 
            "                        UNION ALL SELECT 3 " + 
            "                        UNION ALL SELECT 4 " + 
            "                        UNION ALL SELECT 5 " + 
            "                        UNION ALL SELECT 6 " + 
            "            ) AS t "+ 
            "               WHERE t.temp "+
            "               NOT IN (0,1,2)";
```

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
    public List<Integer> diasFaltantes(long idJornada) {
        List<Integer> allDays = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
        try {
                jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
                List<Integer> numeros = Arrays.asList();
                System.out.println("------->>>>>>--->>>><"+numeros);
                numeros = jdbcTemplate.query(GET_DIAS_FALTANTES_IN_HORARIO, 
                    new Long[]{idJornada}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Integer.class));

                return numeros.size()>0?numeros:allDays;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

El query esta bien, cuando se ejecuta el método se va directo al catch, el System si lo hace, el problema radica en la siguiente linea:

```
numeros = jdbcTemplate.query(GET_DIAS_FALTANTES_IN_HORARIO, 
                    new Long[]{idJornada}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Integer.class));
```

Cuando llega a esta parte me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Integer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
```

No se si sea por la clase Integer o ¿como se debe mapear una lista de enteros?

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví, utilizando el método `queryForList` de la clase `JdbcTemplate`, básicamente estaba retornando una lista de objetos mapeados al utilizar el metodo `query`.

Entonces con `queryForList` retorne una lista del mismo tipo del elemento que se le pasa como segundo parámetro así que le paso la clase `Integer` para que obtener esa lista de números, el método resuelto:

```
@Override
    public List<Integer> diasFaltantes(long idJornada){
        List<Integer> allDays = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
        try {
                jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
                List<Integer> numeros = Arrays.asList();
                numeros = (List<Integer>)jdbcTemplate.queryForList(GET_DIAS_FALTANTES_IN_HORARIO, Integer.class, new Object[]{idJornada});

                return numeros.size()>0?numeros:allDays;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR----->: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que si usas `new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Integer.class)` se entiende que realizas una consulta para un valor único, en este caso un valor entero, no un Listado de valores:

```
 Integer valor = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, args, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Integer.class));
```

Para obtener un listado es correcto usar `jdbcTemplate.query()`, pero en este caso debes crear un objeto, por ejemplo:

```
 public List<Jornada> findJornadas() {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";

        List<jornada> jornadas = jdbcTemplate.query(
                sql,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Jornada.class));

        return jornadas;
    }
```

o también usando  `jdbcTemplate.queryForList()`

```
public List<Jornada> findJornadas() {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Jornada";

        List<Jornada> Jornadas = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);

        for (Map row : rows) {
            Jornada obj = new Jornada();
            obj.setID(((Integer) row.get("idJornada")).longValue());
            obj.setName((String) row.get("nombre"));        
            Jornadas.add(obj);
        }

        return Jornadas;
    }
```

**[Ejemplos de consultas Spring JdbcTemplate](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/)**